How to retrieve previous values from a SQLAlchemy session before an update?
I'm working on a project using SQLAlchemy to interact with a database. Currently, I'm implementing an auditing functionality that requires accessing the previous values of objects before updates are made to the database.
I've tried using the before_flush event to capture the previous values before updates are made, but I'm getting in values_before and values_after both the new commited values.
I've also tried @event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'before_update') with the same results.
Here's my current implementation:
def register_audit_events(db):
    @event.listens_for(db.session, 'before_flush')
    def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
        for obj in session.dirty:
            if isinstance(obj, (StoreModel, ItemModel, TagModel)):
                # Here I try to store de previous values
                obj._previous_values = {c.name: getattr(obj, c.name) for c in obj.__table__.columns}

    @event.listens_for(db.session, 'after_flush')
    def after_flush(session, flush_context):
        user_id = session.info.get('user_id')
        
        for obj in session.new:
            if isinstance(obj, (StoreModel, ItemModel, TagModel)):
                operation = 'CREATE'
                values = json.dumps({c.name: getattr(obj, c.name)
                                    for c in obj.__table__.columns})
                log_audit_event(obj, operation, user_id, None, values)

        for obj in session.dirty:
            if isinstance(obj, (StoreModel, ItemModel, TagModel)):
                # Auditoría del evento de actualización
                operation = 'UPDATE'
                values_before = json.dumps(obj._previous_values)  # I use the supposed previous values 
                values_after = json.dumps(
                    {c.name: getattr(obj, c.name) for c in obj.__table__.columns})
                log_audit_event(obj, operation, user_id,
                                values_before, values_after)

        for obj in session.deleted:
            if isinstance(obj, (StoreModel, ItemModel, TagModel)):
                operation = 'DELETE'
                values = json.dumps({c.name: getattr(obj, c.name)
                                    for c in obj.__table__.columns})
                log_audit_event(obj, operation, user_id, values, None)

What might I be doing wrong in my current implementation? Is there any other way to retrieve the previous values from the session before an update in SQLAlchemy?
Thanks in advance.

The History object might be useful here. See also the Versioning Examples.
